# re-run with -feature for details, How to see scala feature warnings when building with gradle?

Tags: scala, build, gradle, scalac

The gradle scala plugin adds the `compileScala` task to the project. But sometimes the scala compiler might report something like the following:

```
$ gradle compileScala 
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE 
:compileScala 
[ant:scalac] warning: there were 3 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details     
[ant:scalac] one warning found

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 21.796 secs
```

I tried to re-run with -feature but the gradle build complained as follows:

```
$ gradle compileScala -feature

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Problem configuring task :compileScala from command line.
> Unknown command-line option '-f'.

* Try:
Run gradle help --task :compileScala to get task usage details. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.792 secs
```

gradle help --task :compileScala did not provide any useful information.

The question is, when using gradle to compile scala code, how does one pass the -feature option to the scala compiler to see the feature warnings?

**EDIT**

Just in case this is useful:

```
$ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.12
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2014-04-29 09:24:31 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     a831fa866d46cbee94e61a09af15f9dd95987421

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.7.0_55 (Oracle Corporation 24.55-b03)
OS:           Linux 3.13.0-27-generic amd64

$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.10.3 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Checking `ScalaCompile` in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html) leads to:

```
compileScala { // or: tasks.withType(ScalaCompile)
    scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = ["-feature"]
}
```

By the way, `scalaCompileOptions.useAnt = false` will switch from the Ant compiler to the incremental Zinc compiler, which is also used by sbt.

Comment: I have the same problem but I don't understand the answer. What does it mean to "re-run with -feature" ? How do I do that?